# Rails Rack::Cache and Middleware redirect based on header for mobile devices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rack

**How can I write a Rack Middleware to redirect a user to a different subdomain based on the User Agent string? I need this to run before Rack::Cache in my rails app, and I also would like this middleware to be able to detect the presence of a cookie.**

- We have a mobile optimized site on a subdomain ("m.domain.com").
- If a visitor comes to "www.domain.com" and we recognize the user agent string as a mobile device, and they do not already have a cookie set that says they prefer the full site, then we redirect them to the mobile subdomain. This is currently done in our ApplicationController in a before filter.

Currently if we set cache headers in our rails app for the home page, Rack::Cache caches the home page but when a mobile user visits the main "www" domain, Rack::Cache serves up the cached version of the page without hitting the rest of our rails app, so our mobile redirect is never executed.

It would seem as though I will have to move our mobile redirect solution into middleware that executes before Rack::Cache. For context, here is what our filters look like in our ApplicationController:

```
before_filter :set_mobile_preferences
before_filter :redirect_to_mobile_if_applicable  

def set_mobile_preferences
  if params[:mobile_site]
    cookies.delete(:prefer_web)
  elsif params[:full_site]
    cookies.permanent[:prefer_web] = 1
    redirect_to_full_site if mobile_request?
  end
end

# before filter
def redirect_to_mobile_if_applicable
  if mobile_device? && !mobile_request? && !prefers_full_site?
    new_url = request.protocol + domain_prefixes[:mobile] + '.' +
              request.host_with_port.gsub(/^#{domain_prefixes[:web]}?\./, '') + 
              request.fullpath
    redirect_to new_url and return
  end
end
```

Does anyone have experience with both caching pages *and* redirecting mobile users to an alternate domain? Does moving this redirection to middleware before the cache layer seem like the right solution?

Any tips, links, suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update:** Maybe I can use the `Vary: User-Agent` header to help with the cache issue? However, I'm concerned if I do this then the cache will fill up with multiple copies of the same page because of the hundreds of variations on User-Agent strings sent by browsers.

Answer (score 4):

So, I've decided to write our own middleware to detect mobile user-agent strings, redirect to a subdomain, and also detect the presence of a site-preference cookie so we only redirect users based on user-agent only if they have not specified otherwise. I moved this up in the Rack stack so it executes before Rack::Cache and that seems to fix our issue. You can view the source here: https://gist.github.com/3630760